# deleting the last 100.000 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a short url website with where i have user stats for the urls. i wonder how i can delete the last 100.000 entrys in the database? the database is 2.000.000 entrys big and i don't need a lot of it so i need to delete some stuff.

I tried to use "`DELETE FROM` stats `WHERE dt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR);`"

but it times out after several hours when running it trough SSH terminal soo i need to go backwards deleting 100.000 entrys by 100.000 if i can.

Comment: Is `dt` indexed (include the output from `show create table stats` in the question by editing it)? Is the table innodb? How big is the innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size?

Comment: if you set auto commit to false you can optimize the operation, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-transaction-management.html

Comment: the only answer here i can give is that the table is innodb.

Comment: what about `delete from stats where id < 100,000 ` or  id > 1,900,000?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like

```
DELETE
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 stats WHERE dt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

might need a little tweaking. read about `WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained **why** this is a better option (if, indeed is is a better option)